# UnknownError when deleting files from Digital Ocean Spaces

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, digital-ocean

I use digital ocean spaces and use the aws-sdk for uploading/deleting files from it. I've had this code running for awhile, but since about 2 weeks ago its throwing an error.

```
const listResponse = await this.getDirectoryListing(directory, prefix)
const files = listResponse.Contents ? listResponse.Contents!.map((item) => item.Key!) : []

if (files.length > 0) {
  await this.s3.delete({
    bucket: this.config.env.S3_PUBLIC_BUCKET,
    keys: files,
  })
  this.logger.debug('Old files deleted', { files })
}
```

The error thrown is

```
"type": "S3ServiceException",
"message": "UnknownError",
"stack":
   XAmzContentSHA256Mismatch: UnknownError
```

The s3.delete method looks like this

```
  async delete(options: IS3Delete): Promise<DeleteObjectsCommandOutput> {
    const deleteObjectsCommand = {
      Bucket: options.bucket,
      Delete: {
        Objects: options.keys.map((item) => ({ Key: item })),
      },
    }

    return this.client.send(new DeleteObjectsCommand(deleteObjectsCommand))
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

We found that updating our `@aws-sdk/client-s3` version did the trick.

For example, our previous version was: `"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.18.0"`, the new version is `"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.427.0"`

The issue was possibly an incompatibility with newer node versions. We recently updated from `node 16` to `node 20`. The problem started after that update.